# Why am I not seeing current content in my frontend and backend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, browser

I am using a templated Joomla3 system (Joomla version 3.4.8) and have one problem that's causing disfunctionality to the whole site.

The problem persists in the backend as well as on the frontend. I will try to describe the problem:

When I open one link, let's say any module, I change the name of the module, save and close it. Then if I reopen it, I don't see the new name in the module until I refresh my browser.

Let's try with another example. When I open one page on the website, go to another page (in the mean time the first page has been changed), then go back to the first page, I see the old content (not the changed one)...until I do a REFRESH in the browser.

It's something like when you open a page, go to another, then you want to go to last one and do a "back" in browser and do not use a regular link which should open that page refreshed.

Comment: Have you have caching enabled? Check your Joomla Global Config **and** Hosting control panel

Comment: Joomla chaching is disabled. Other Joomla based websites are working on the same hosting account. Still haven't figured out what the problem could be....

Comment: The template is based on T3 and virtuemart

Comment: QUESTIONS: 1. Does the problem occur for others or just you?  2) Have you tried Web Developer Toolbar and does a RESET PAGE (http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with browser caching. You should disable it in your `.htaccess` file and then you won't have to do any refresh. See this post on how to do that: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-disable-browser-caching-in-joomla-backend

If you're wondering what is causing this problem, then it is most likely your server which is explicitly requesting from the browser to use cached versions of the pages. This problem is common with websites using shared hosting (especially SiteGround).